# Call bean method from XML configutaion

Tags: spring-bean

I have a bean which is initialized with some content (a collection with a few built-in elements). I'd like to ship this pre-configured bean with my library.

At the same time I'd like to give the user of the library the possibility *to insert his or her own elements into this collection* (currently done from code by calling an `addDocument()` function).

Is there a way to achieve this from the configuration? How is this problem addressed in other libraries?